# Celda final se duplica cuando hace salto de pagina en el PDF / itext 7

Tags: java, android, itext

Buen día, tengo un problema cuando genero un PDF con **itext 7** resulta que he agregado un código para que asigne el total final a la ultima celda de una tabla quiere decir que esa celda siempre será la última independientemente los datos que tenga, sin embargo resulta que cuando e PDF hace un salto de pagina el total final se queda al final (valga la redundancia) de la primera pagina como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo correcto es que solo se agregue al final en este caso tendría que reflejarse el total en la segunda pagina, y nada mas ese el el problema que presento, el código para agregar una celda siempre al final de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
table.addFooterCell(new Cell(0,6).add(new Paragraph("TOTAL: $ " + formatoDecimal.format(gTotal)).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
```

Y eso es todo si necesitan mas código por favor decirme, espere me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estas agregando un "Footer" y se entiende que esto aplica para todas las paginas,  en este caso puedes validar en que pagina agregar el "Footer", por ejemplo:

```
if (document.getPageNumber() == 1){ //Agrega footer en la primera pàgina.
    table.addFooterCell(new Cell(0,6).add(new Paragraph("TOTAL: $ " + formatoDecimal.format(gTotal)).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
}
```

---

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> parece funcionar pero tengo un problema los productos que yo voy
> agregando son dinámicos por lo tanto hay ocasiones en las que ocupan
> solo una pagina y ocasiones en las que ocupan 2 o 3 paginas en ese
> caso el if siempre entraría cuando es una pagina

La validación debería realizarse para agregar el "Footer" en la última página por lo tanto puedes realizarlo haciendo uso también del método `getNumberOfPages()`:

```
if (document.getPageNumber() == document.getNumberOfPages()){ //Agrega footer en la última.
    table.addFooterCell(new Cell(0,6).add(new Paragraph("TOTAL: $ " + formatoDecimal.format(gTotal)).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda tu respuesta parece funcionar pero tengo un problema los productos que yo voy agregando son dinámicos por lo tanto hay ocasiones en las que ocupan solo una pagina y ocasiones en las que ocupan 2 o 3 paginas en ese caso el if siempre entraría cuando es una pagina pero cuando son 2 o mas no lo aria

Comment: Hola Adiel, revisa la actualización, saludos

Comment: Gracias Elenasys, pero enfrento un nuevo problema en primer lugar directamente de Document no puedo pasar getPageNumber tampoco getNumberOfPages sin embargo de PdfDocument si puedo hacerlo lo cual quedaria de la siguiente manera ´if (pdfDocument.getPageNumber()  == pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages())´ pero el nuevo problema que enfrento en que getPageNumber necesita que le pase un parametro que se extienda de 'PdfPage' pero sinceramente no se que le tengo que pasar